# ActiveResource for Gitlab CI API in Rails 4.2.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeresource, gitlab-ci

Sorry for my english.

I develop Ruby On Rails app (4.2.4) which interacts with Gitlab CI API ( using ActiveResource). I have list of projects on my remote resource and want to get it.

I created model GitlabResource:

```
require 'active_resource'
class GitlabResource < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = 'http://gitlab.example.com/ci'
  self.include_format_in_path = false
end
```

And Project model

```
class Project < GitlabResource
  self.prefix = '/api/v1/'
end
```

The docs says that one of the ways of authentication is with **GitLab user token & GitLab url**. And I need to add this parameters in each request.

when I use curl it works well:

```
curl http://gitlab.example.com/ci/api/v1/projects?private_token=AAAAQQQQAAAd&url=http://gitlab.example.com/
```

How can I add these parameters to the model GitlabResource? And do something like this:

```
@projects = Project.all
```

**Upd.**
When I do

```
@projects = Project.find(:all, :params => { :private_token => 'AAAAQQQQAAAd', :url => 'http://gitlab.example.com/'})
```

Get error

```
Failed. Response code = 500. Response message = Internal Server Error.
```

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Project < GitlabResource
  headers["PRIVATE-TOKEN"] = 'AAAAQQQQAAAd'
  self.prefix = '/ci/api/v1/'
end
```

It works well now.